# Test Wordpress on Windows / IE with virtual machine

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, virtual-machine, host

I'm on a Mac computer, and **I need to test a Wordpress website on IE / Windows**. I have some VMs (Virtual Box) that can do the job, but **I need the site URL to be the same as my localhost URL (as it's Wordpress configuration)**.

So, I read some articles and here's what I've done so far :

My conf :

```
localhost:8888/myproject (MAMP server)
```

On the Windows (VM) host file :

```
192.168.0.20    localhost
```

Assuming 192.168.0.20 is the local address of my MAMP server on my Mac. So I saved the host file, but nothing happens, IE can't find the document. When I go directly to 192.168.0.20 I can see the project without its assets (no images, css, etc.).

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I asked to soon : it appears that Windows just take some time to apply the changes I made in host file (about 5 minutes).

Nevermind, hope this helps anyway :)